# JB4A-SDK-Android Device-Registration not working

Tags: journeybuilder, android, mobilepush-android, salesforce-sdk-android

I included the JB4A-SDK-Android SDK 4.4.1 like described in the documentation, but my device wont show up in the mobilepush marketing cloud.

It seems that there is a problem with the device registration but i'm out of ideas. I even compared the integration from the LearningAppAndroid but cant't see a difference... I attached the debug log below. 
It seems that the **ETPushService** is not being called in my app, does anyone have an idea why or in which direction I should search?

**log**: http://pastebin.com/mWMfQt9y

The log output stops after these lines and the device won't register. I waited for a long time, but nothing happens.

Thanks in advance for any help!

regards

Daniel

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have more than 1 service declared in your application then there's a Google bug in their GcmReceiver which may be getting in your way.  See https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/128740/16482 for details, but net-net-net, manually declare the ETPushReceiver in your manifest and ensure that it is the 1st service listed.

Comment: Thanks Bill,

you were right, that was the problem:

**before**:

GcmReceiver  D  Restricting intent to a specific service: de.***.android.auth.IPCAuthenticatorService

**after**:

GcmReceiver  D  Restricting intent to a specific service: com.exacttarget.etpushsdk.ETPushService

Comment: I have reported this bug.  Looking into a work around is also on the product backlog ;)